# Using PerformanceCounter.GetNext()

Tags: c#

Can anybody tell me why this doesn't work. My guess is its something to do with instantiation or the global values.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

namespace UtilApp
{
    class Perf
    {
        #region Performance Counters
        // CPU utilization
        PerformanceCounter CPU_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        // Memory left
        PerformanceCounter MEM_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        // System Up time
        PerformanceCounter SYS_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
        #endregion

        public int getUsedCPU()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Requested CPU Usage...");
            int v = (int) CPU_Perf.NextValue();
            Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", v);
            return v;
        }

        public int getFreeMEM()
        {
            return (int) MEM_Perf.NextValue();
        }

        public int getUpTime()
        {
            return (int) SYS_Perf.NextValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, getUsedCPU() always returns 0, when I know that is not true. I copied this over from a console application I built using a tutorial online.

I'm accessing it from a form to show CPU usage like so...

```
Perf p = new Perf;
label1.text = p.getUsedCPU().toString();
```

NOTE: the console.writeline are for debugging, but still get 0 without them.

Comment: What does Console.WriteLine output?

Comment: Requested CPU Usage... 0

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Aside from everything else, I'd *strongly* recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions as soon as possible, before you get into bad habits.

Comment: thanks, yeah your right about the naming conventions... any good links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue.aspx)

> If the calculated value of a counter depends on two counter reads, the
>   first read operation returns 0.0.

So, if you call once more the method, then you will get that you are looking for.

Furthermore, from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To obtain performance data for counters that required an initial or
>   previous value for performing the necessary calculation, call the
>   NextValue method twice and use the information returned as your
>   application requires.
>
> Why this happens?

This happens, as Jon mentioned in his comment, because the OP is creating a new instance of `Perf` each time.

Comment: It might be worth giving the reason this is important - the OP is creating a new instance of `Perf` each time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class constructor, then create the instance of objects:

```
PerformanceCounter CPU_Perf;
PerformanceCounter MEM_Perf;
PerformanceCounter SYS_Perf;

public Perf()
{
        PerformanceCounter CPU_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("Processor Information", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
        PerformanceCounter MEM_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
        PerformanceCounter SYS_Perf = new PerformanceCounter("System", "System Up Time");
}
```

Comment: I get a NullReference Error on this line...int v = (int) CPU_Perf.NextValue();

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in UtilApp.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: its ok, if i remove the PerformanceCounter from the start of the lines in the constructor it works

Comment: @JimmyHowe is correct, i'am wrong in the code. Sorry, i will edit. But, you are using a function for each Counter, put a declaration and initialization in each method.